# Proper Function Syntax to change the text when you click a button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, function

My instructor is confusing us on the syntax to create a function that fully replaces the paragraph and words from an object inside of an array.

She also did not explain the line break syntax and how to properly concatenate the line break string.

What am I doing wrong in my function syntax?

Why do we use a function and not alert?

```js
var button = document.getElementById("scinfo");
var states = {
  "eachstate": [{
      "Name": "North Carolina",
      "Capital": "Raleigh",
      "Population": "986,000",
      "StateBird": "Who Cares"

    },

    {
      "Name": "South Carolina",
      "Capital": "Columbia",
      "Population": "886,000",
      "StateBird": "Hawk"

    },


    {
      "Name": "Florida",
      "Capital": "Tallahasee",
      "Population": "975,000",
      "StateBird": "Flamingo"
    },

  ]
};

button.addEventListener("click", writestates, false);

function writestates() {
  document.getElementById("StateInfo").innerHTML = "<p>Name: " + states.eachstate[0].name + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Capital: " +
    states.eachstate[0].capital + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Bird: " + states.eachstate[0].bird + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Population: " +
    states.eachstate[0].population + "</p>"
}
```

```html
<!-- Create a button to write out ONLY SC information when clicked -->
<button id="states" type="button">SC Information</button>

<div class="showstate">
  <h1>
    South Carolina
  </h1>

  <p id="StateInfo">
    This is where the new information should show up!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: does `var button = document.getElementById("scinfo");` even exist in your html?

Comment: what is it that you're trying to do exactly? You only have one button and one state listed. Are you trying to list them all?

Comment: Your English is unclear. Try to use some kind of translator or use https://es.stackoverflow.com instead.
Also, if you're working on multiple files, separate the content of each file, since it appears you're sourcing nonexistent file.

Comment: @zfrisch I need the text to change to information in the second object inside of the array "eachstate"

Comment: What do you need to change it into?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier  To the onformation in the object below                                                                                      
        "Name": "South Carolina",
        "Capital": "Columbia",
        "Population": "886,000",
        "StateBird": "Hawk"

Comment: Okay, couple of pointers. 1. Remove `"eachstates"` from the `states` variable and make `states` the array. e.g. `var states = [ {...}, {...}, {...} ]`. That makes more sense. 2. `var button = ...` does not select an element. There is no element with the ID of `scinfo` but there is one with `states`. Change that to select the right ID. 3. In your `writestates` function use a **loop**. Check [this page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for). MDN is now going to be your best friend on how to write JavaScript. Do those things and update above.

Comment: There is no JSON involved in this question. JSON is a text format used when passing data between different contexts. You just have an object.

Comment: I've edited your question to clear up some of the language used, and to include a Stack Snippet so that it's clearer what the issues are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer:

- Your button has an identifier of `states`, **not** `scinfo`

  - change button to `document.getElementById("states")` **not** `document.getElementById("scinfo")`, because that ID **doesn't exist**.
- You need to use the correct **index**.

  - You're pointing at the array `states.eachstate` but providing the index of **zero**( [0] ) which looks at the **first** item.
  - The South Carolina information is in the *second* item, which has an index of **one**. ( [1] )
- You need to provide the case-correct `property` names that correlate with the **data**. These are **case-sensitive**

  - `states.eachstate[1].population` **is not the same** as `states.eachstate[1].Population`
- You need to provide the **correct** property name.

  - You use `states.eachstate[0].bird` when in your data it's listed as `states.eachstate[0].StateBird`

### Example:

```js
var button = document.getElementById("states");
var states = {


    "eachstate": [
        {
        "Name":"North Carolina",
        "Capital": "Raleigh",
        "Population": "986,000",
        "StateBird": "Who Cares"

    },

        {
        "Name": "South Carolina",
        "Capital": "Columbia",
        "Population": "886,000",
        "StateBird": "Hawk"

    },


        {
        "Name": "Florida",
        "Capital": "Tallahasee",
        "Population": "975,000",
        "StateBird": "Flamingo"
            },

    ]
};

button.addEventListener("click", writestates, false);
function writestates()
{
    document.getElementById("StateInfo").innerHTML = "<p>Name: " + states.eachstate[1].Name + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Capital: "
        + states.eachstate[1].Capital + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Bird: " + states.eachstate[1].StateBird + "</p>" + "<p>" + "Population: " +
        states.eachstate[1].Population + "</p>"
}
```

```html
<button id="states" type="button">SC Information</button>

<div class="showstate" >
    <h1>
        South Carolina
    </h1>

    <p id="StateInfo">
        This is where the new information should show up!
    </p>
</div>
```